# Why responsive video height is different between youtube and vimeo

Tags: responsive

I made a bootstrap grid with the embed video from Youtube and Vimeo side by side. They are responsive with 16:9 ratio But I'm wondering about why the height of them is different? How to fix it? Thanks

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
<h2>Youtube</h2>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RBumgq5yVrA?autoplay=0&start=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&disablekb=1&playsinline=1&cc_lang_pref=auto&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <h2>Vimeo</h2>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/304704403?autoplay=0&api=1"></iframe>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put your code here, not in `codepen`, and use the code syntax for that, not for regular text. I would also suggest posting a screenshot so we see what you mean.